# How to shorten/simplify my plotting code

Tags: plotting, simplifying-expressions

Is there a way to simplify and shorten my code?

```
data = Table[Import["files/abs"<>ToString[i]<>".csv","CSV"],{i,12}];
ListLinePlot[{data[[1]],data[[2]],data[[3]],data[[4]],data[[6]],data[[7]], 
data[[8]],data[[9]],data[[10]],data[[11]],data[[12]]},
PlotLegends->{"1","2","3","4","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"}]
```

Note that `data[[5]]` should be left out, because abs5.csv is empty.

The input files abs1..12.csv (except abs5.csv) have the folling structure:

```
{{700.044, 0.0841635}, {699.037, 0.0855728}, ... ,{400.974, 0.187245}, {400.047, 0.188687}}
```

`data` is a list of those.

Maybe it would be easier to just not import abs5.csv?

Comment: This gives me an error: `Drop::drop: Cannot drop positions 5 through 5 in {}.`

Comment: This is what happens when you provide no code to work with :)

Comment: The code I posted in my question is all the code I use. I just cut the parts out, which are not important for the question. Should I edit my original post and add my complete code?

Comment: I meant, the minimal example of data set is needed. ListLinePlot can work with lists of points or lists of numbers.

Comment: edited. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fulldata = Table[RandomReal[], {10}, {30}];
```

If you want *short/simple* plotting code:

```
  ListLinePlot[
  Drop[fulldata,{5}],
  PlotLegends -> Delete[Range[10], 5]]
```

[image]